# Modifying user.js in headless Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, headless

As far as I can tell, this is not possible in Chrome without the use of extensions so no viable solution.  I believe this can be achieved through Firefox user.js.   Has anyone found a workaround for this or is there no current workaround for windows users.  I have also tried to modify the user.js as to add GitHub projects with JavaScript but no luck thus far.

Comment: You can modify chrome preferences to a pretty large extent, but Firefox is your man if you want to use user.js.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. `user.js` has a different meaning between chrome and firefox.

Comment: @FlorentB. I'm trying to add javascript through user.js to browsers Chrome and Firefox headless as to combat fingerprinting.  I believe this can be done in Firefox but from what I've read this can only be done in Chrome with extensions which is a shame.  I'm curious as to if someone has got around this.

Comment: You need to be more specific. With Firefox user.js is the file holding the preferences for the profile. For Chrome it is supposed to be a grease monkey like script. Fingerprinting can easily be defeated with Selenium by overriding some properties in the page. The difficulty is to inject the script before  the page starts executing the fingerprinting. But it can be done with either Chrome or Firefox with Selenium and at runtime.

Comment: @FlorentB. Sounds interesting.  I have not read much on doing this with Selenium itself but had heard it was not possible with headless chrome to use user.js  Any examples on combating canvasing through selenium.  I can't really think of anything outside of user.js to pass against: http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs, http://browserleaks.com/canvas, http://browserleaks.com/javascript, http://panopticlick.eff.org, http://whoer.net

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered. You added the Selenium tag which implies that your issue is with Selenium by we still don't know the context, your purpose, and what user.js is supposed to be and do.

Comment: @FlorentB. I would like to use Selenium.  The goal here is to combat  privacy and tracking however possible through Selenium or through Firefox and Chrome so to use in Selenium.  I have not seen much on this topic which is a shame.